# Creating new rows for listed substrings

Tags: r

My goal is to create a wordcloud in R, but I'm working with nested JSON data (which also happens to be incredibly messy).

There's a nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937960/creating-word-cloud-of-phrases-not-individual-words-in-r) for how to create a wordcloud of phrases rather than singular words. I also know melt() from reshape2 can create new rows out of entire columns. Is there a way in R to perform a melt-like function over nested substrings?

Example:

```
N        Group     String
1        A         c("a", "b", c")
2        A         character(0)
3        B         a
4        B         c("b", d")
5        B         d
```

...should become:

```
N        Group     String
1        A         a
2        A         b
3        A         c
4        A         character(0)
5        B         a
6        B         b
7        B         d
8        B         d
```

...where each subsequent substring is returned to the next row. In my actual data, the pattern c("x, y") is consistent but the substrings are too varied to know a priori.

If there's no great way to do this, too bad... just thought I'd ask the experts!

Comment: Would it be possible to load your json data into a `list` rather than a `data.frame`? If so, then you can use `unlist` to separate all the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(listcites, sep = ",") %>% # split on commas
  dmap_at("listcites", ~ gsub("^c\\(\"|\")$|\"", "", .x)) # clean up the quotations and parens
```

Comment: It was brought to my attention that this question is a duplicate. However, none of the answers on the linked page solved my problem. Yours did. +1