# How to amend this code slightly to produce correct word cloud in R?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud

Suppose we have a data frame (`df`) containing comments (each row is a comment):

```
comment
Amazing job
Terrible work
```

And we have a dictionary (`dict`) of positive and negative words:

```
positive negative
amazing  terrible
```

I'm trying to create two word clouds: one of the positive comment in `df`, and one of negative comment in `df`. To do this, I tried the following code but run into an error. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
library("quanteda")

corpus_example <- corpus(df)
head(corpus_example)

Output:

text1:
"Amazing job"

text2:
"Terrible work"
```

Next, create dfm:

```
comments_dfm <- dfm(corpus_example, dictionary = dict)
head(comments_dfm)

Output:
      positive negative
text1 1        0
text2 0        1
```

I.e. it shows how many positive and negative words (according to `dict`) exist within `text1` and `text2`. `text1` is considered positive and `text2` is considered negative.

Finally, I try to create word clouds using `textplot_wordcloud(comments_dfm)`, but this just returns a word cloud containing the headers of `comments_dfm`, i.e. the words `positive` and `negative`. Instead, I want two word clouds: one containing `Amazing job` (because it's considered a positive comment), the other containing `Terrible work` (because it's a negative comment).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So a few things:

- The reason `positive` and `negative` appear is because you've "mapped" `Amazing job` and `Terrible work` to those respective categories. We use dictionaries to correspond raw text to different categories so that we may interpret the data in a meaningful way (e.g. analyzing word frequency to understand sentiment).
- However, I don't think you need quanteda at all; see below example for positive wordcloud
- Since you want to preserve phrases, use `table`; see [Creating "word" cloud of phrases, not individual words in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937960/creating-word-cloud-of-phrases-not-individual-words-in-r)

```
library(wordcloud)

df <- data.frame(comment = c("Amazing job",
                             "Terrible work",
                             "Great job",
                             "Great job",
                             "Great job",
                             "Great job",
                             "Fantastic job",
                             "Fantastic job",
                             "Fantastic job",
                             "Amazing job",
                             "Amazing job",
                             "Terrible work",
                             "Terrible work"))

dict <- list(
  Positive = c("Amazing","Great","Fantastic"),
  Negative = c("Terrible","Bad","Suck")
)

# finds positive comments / negative comments depending on input
find_matches <- function(comments,dictionary){
  comments[grepl(paste(dictionary,collapse = "|"),
                 comments,
                 ignore.case = TRUE)]
}

# Since you want phrases, using table
positive_table <- table(find_matches(df$comment, dict$Positive))
wordcloud::wordcloud(
  names(positive_table),
  as.numeric(positive_table),
  scale = c(2, 1),
  min.freq = 3,
  max.words = 100,
  random.order = T
)
```